# Is there a way to use the groupby function in pandas so that something could be referenced as 0?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this CSV file that I'm using in Pandas, and it contains info on if a post it pulled from online has a certain word in it. So let's say I'm looking at sports, the CSV file basically looks like this:

```
Date of Post       Sport Mentioned
9-22               Basketball
9-22               Hockey
9-22               Football
9-24               Baseball
9-24               Hockey
9-24               Football
```

I want it so that when I use groupby('Date of Post').count(), it would show 0 on 9-23, since there's no mention of any sport on that date. Is there a way to do this? I'm pretty certain that pandas sees the first column as being dates, not just a regular string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.resample`:

```
df['Date of Post'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of Post'], format='%m-%d')
df.resample('D', on='Date of Post').size()

Date of Post
1900-09-22    3
1900-09-23    0
1900-09-24    3
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

If you want to add the correct year, use:

```
df['Date of Post'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-' + df['Date of Post'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.resample('D', on='Date of Post').size()

Date of Post
2020-09-22    3
2020-09-23    0
2020-09-24    3
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```